# The matrix exponential of a positive definite matrix is also positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite, matrix-exponential

Let $L$ be a $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix. Prove that for $t>0$ that the matrix exponential $e^{-tL}$ is also symmetric positive definite.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far, and what are you stuck on?

Comment: @anomaly I think I have an answer, it is not too hard as I though at the beginning when I use eigenvalues. Since $L$ is symmetric then the eigenvalues of $-tL$ is real and non-negative. Then, the corresponding eigenvalue $e^{\lambda}$ of $e^{-tL}$ is positive.

Comment: Your approach is fine. Another approach: $\langle x,e^{-tL}x\rangle=\langle x,e^{-tL/2}e^{-tL/2}x\rangle=\langle e^{-tL/2}x,e^{-tL/2}x\rangle>0$ for every $x\ne0$. This argument shows that, more generally, the exponential of any Hermitian matrix is positive definite.